# The Status Of The Split

Tags: discussion, mso-mse-split, announcement

Everything went *remarkably* well. This is what we've got done:

- Meta SO is now a per-site child meta, just like every other meta site (but MSE)
- MSE has been launched in production, and is functioning well
- chat.meta.stackoverflow.com has been relocated to chat.meta.stackexchange.com
- A *lot* of cache / tag engine related things have been fixed following the split

Effectively, it's done, but there's a ton of minor details that still need attention, which we're going to be busy cleaning up for the next day or two. There's design tweaks, tweaks to settings, minor text glitches and other stuff we're working on cleaning up.

I will begin migrating some of the relevant content from MSE back to MSO at some point in the morning on tomorrow (4/17) NY time. We're not yet in a position to fire up the bulk migration tools, but will be very soon. I'll also have a blog post up by tomorrow afternoon, which will basically summarize what we've posted leading up to the split.

I'll be updating this post as things progress - for now, we're split and stable.

**Update**

There are still a bunch of database migrations going on surrounding other projects (mostly tag system improvements), I'm holding off until that's done to start migrating selected posts in bulk.

However, we're starting to 'cherry pick' a few, sending them over manually, which will continue on and off today. I expect to start the *bulk* of sending things back over on Friday,  April 18, as things should be settled and stable by then. For details see [Migrations are now in progress](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250976/migrations-are-now-in-progress).

Just keep doing what you're doing here, which is awesome, and I'm very happy to see you doing it. The old stuff isn't going anywhere, and there's plenty of things to talk about.

SE Blog: [Announcing The Launch Of Meta Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/)

Comment: Is there a post somewhere that describes what will be migrated?  It'd be cool if we didn't have to reopen all our retag / synonym / burnination requests.

Comment: Blog post will be going up in the morning, @Charles. tl;dr: we'll migrate a *few* of these right away, more as we're able to process them. Dumping all of them in at once wouldn't accomplish much.

Comment: Yay. Except for the design.

Comment: This split is bananas!

Comment: *This* is the reason why so many couples divorce every year, it's so stable!

Comment: Now my MSO profile looks poor :(

Comment: I only have 700 rep on this site now :( RIP my 10k user status.

Comment: Great work! Now let us all recover from the split lag.

Comment: @Kasra: but I now have >100k, goodbye limited clickiness! Though I feel like I cheated, somehow...

Comment: @Him at least you have 10K on SO.  I'm can't see deleted posts anymore.

Comment: If I see something on MSO  that should be in MSE, or is even a duplicate of existing MSE question, what should I do?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nothing at this point, though you're welcome to flag as 'other' as bread crumbs for us to have a peek at it when we send content back over. Don't worry about duplicates for now, just answer questions as you can / feel like doing so.

Comment: (It's probably going to be tomorrow before I fire up the bulk migration tools due to unrelated DB migrations still ongoing)

Comment: @Kasra Rahjerdi: Yeah well you're still a dev so quit complaining and get back to work :P

Comment: (a) Did your mother (or [other appropriate authority](http://writers.stackexchange.com)) never tell you that title case means not capitalising *of* and *the*? (b) Why is this on MSO, not MSE?

Comment: @TRiG (a) Apparently not, since the same orthographic defect occurs both in this question’s title and also in the title of the blog post as well. (b) So that more people can edit his post to fix the aforementioned defects. :) (c) As bait to draw more programmers [thither](http://english.stackexchange.com/) and [yonder](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) in search of [***The** One True Way of Title and Headline Casing in the English Language*](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14).