# MSO-MSE-split confusion

Tags: support, reputation, mso-mse-split, badges

The badges are mysteriously disappearing and reappearing on Meta. It seems to only be a meta issue though. The badges were gone from everywhere where they should have been displaying. Recently though when I tried to reload the page, only one bronze badge was displayed.

**EDIT:** All the questions I had asked and answers I had posted are missing, which I hand't noticed at first. This seems like a more serious problem.

Upon further investigation, all of Meta is acting very strangely. None of my questions are showing up, nor any of the answers. The reputation from my SO account is displaying, even after I've cleared my cache. Also my reputation isn't even updating when there is activity.

**UPDATE:** The confusions was over the new MSO split. Please read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own) for more information.

Comment: Oooh, look! [They're back.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235832/wold)

Comment: Also the rep shown is from my SO account, so it could be a caching problem possibly? It seems to far reaching to just be caching though...

Comment: @Wold Per-site metas always just inherit rep from the parent.

Comment: @Wold welcome to Meta Stack Overflow (after the split)

Comment: @AndrewT. I am now even more confused. Care to enlighten me?

Comment: Do you realize that your email address is visible in the screenshot?

Comment: Yes it's public information, but thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's been some changes in how the sites work:

- Meta SO is now a per-site child meta. It is for discussing things that relate to Stack Overflow only, and not any other SE site;
- MSE has been launched. It is where users discuss the workings and policies of the whole Stack Exchange family of Q&A sites.

> Also the rep shown is from my SO account, so it could be a caching problem possibly? It seems to far reaching to just be caching though

Nope, this one is not a caching problem. Per-site meta sites always (with the exception of MSO previously) derive rep from their parent-site. Now that MSO is only about Stack Overflow, your MSO account will inherit the rep from your Stack Overflow profile. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

For more details, see:

- [Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own)
- [Operation 'Split, All The Metas!' Shall Commence On April 16, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014)
- [The Status Of The Split](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250024/the-status-of-the-split)

Comment: As said in a comment on the question, "per-site metas just inherit rep from the parent."  So they have an effect on MSO and SO, but not MSE

Comment: @stevesliva Ok, my activity on this site seems to be having no effect on my reputation. Where is it going?

Comment: I'm wondering too.  I see none of my SO badges here and don't see the latest rep posted on SO here.  Could be a delay, could be a bug, but I've got *most* of my SO rep.

Comment: @Wold: meta sites simply don't have reputation. The score displayed is that of the main site (+/- some caching effects). Badges on the other hand can be earned on meta sites. MSE is an exception. MSO was an exception but no longer is.