# What is the difference between Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, meta, mso-mse-split, accounts

What is the difference between Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange?

I have these two accounts:

- [Account one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1108032/boris-strandjev)
- [Account two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178998/boris-strandjev)

My Meta account looked like the first one, but the second holds my stats for up until few weeks. Now I have the first account, which has my SO rating and only one question - the one that I asked today. I think there must have been complete messup with these two (that is why I am opening this question as bug report).

Issue description:

- Two account for Meta
- One of them with SO rating
- I got two yearling badges on the wrong account due to my wrong rating.
- Now I have questions / answers on both.

PS: I wonder to which of these two accounts will this question go?

Comment: [What is Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). What is [Meta Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014

Comment: @Oded Maybe i do not see correctly, but none of the links justifies two places for doing jus tthe same?

Comment: It isn't **the same**. Stack Exchange has over 120 sites right now. **Each** has a dedicated Meta site for discussing issues for **that specific community**. Meta Stack Overflow was the one for Stack Overflow, but for a historical accident was also one for the **entire** network (things that are not specific to any one site). It was split into two sites each serving a different (if somewhat overlapping) audience.

Comment: related: [What kind of questions should we ask on Meta Stack Overflow and on Meta Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250020/what-kind-of-questions-should-we-ask-on-meta-stack-overflow-and-on-meta-stack-ex)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Status Of The Split](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250024/the-status-of-the-split) and of [MSO-MSE-split confusion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250054/mso-mse-split-confusion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug.

Until a few weeks ago this site didn't exist in its current form, but was the name used for Meta Stack Exchange. It was a separate site - hence the separate account and reputation etc. However, it wasn't fulfilling it's dual role of support for Stack Overflow and the whole Stack Exchange network very well - particularly the Stack Overflow support role.

It was decided a while ago that Stack Overflow should have it's own child meta - like all the other sites in the Stack Exchange network and that the (then) current meta site should be renamed and take on the official role of support for network wide issues and careers.

This is why your history on this site doesn't go back very far, has the same reputation as your Stack Overflow profile (because that's the way child metas work), but has Yearling badges because that just how things work.

Comment: Why the same reputation? Does any upvote / downvote in here affect my other account?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev - that's the way child metas work. It allows you to have contrary opinions and (more importantly) down-vote answers without losing reputation.

Comment: Why the badges then?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev The badges reflect the votes here. It's not that intuitive but it works.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: The badges are the only remaining indicator of participation. Someone with meta badges has participated in the discussion and / or sought or provided support.