# Why aren't the user accounts linked in migrated questions?

Tags: support, mso-mse-split, migration

[The MSO-MSE split has finally happened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250024/2024761) and the very [first question migration done was this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250033/2024761). But I do not understand why the user accounts in that question are not linked? I can see that only [Shog's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) account is linked and all the other user accounts(the answerers) are not linked yet. As far as I know, if a migration happens and the user does not have an account in the migrated site, only then the account is not linked but in this most of users do have their accounts on the new MSO. Why aren't the accounts linked to the posts then? Can someone throw some light on this?

[image: Account Not Linked]

Comment: Probably a symptom of a Behaviour of Unexpected Genius.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't get a profile on a child meta by default. You still have to visit the site to have the profile created for you even if you participate on the main site.

If you look at /users right now and try to search for, say, ThiefMaster, you'll see that there's no MSO profile for him yet. He'll create one later, I'm sure, and then his contribution to that question would be properly linked up to his profile on this site... if the migration history wasn't cleared on that question.

I'll reassociate your answer with your profile, and we'll probably have to (eventually) do the same with the other ones on that question. Although honestly, it doesn't matter as much here since posts don't affect your MSO reputation, etc.

Comment: Yeah I know that it doesn't affect the reputation. I'm more concerned about looking for them in future. If it were linked to my account, it would be easier to find it than having to search it on MSO. This is just the start of the migration I guess. So this might become a bit troublesome in the future with more questions being migrated. Because having to link the accounts manually so many posts, is really going to be a problem, for the mods and the devs I suppose.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ Clearing migration history is a manual step. If it becomes problematic, we can just not do that for a while until most profiles have been recreated and post ownerships remapped.

Comment: @OneKitten Comments are never reassociated if the author doesn't already have an account at the time of the migration.

Comment: @AnnaLear: oh wait, my bad, that was something else. Sorry.

Comment: I tend to associate the default gray user icon with “user has deleted his account, question probably isn't worth answering“. I guess the user wouldn't receive any notifications even if his question got answered now, right? So I'd very much welcome any automatic process to create MSO accounts for everyone whose posts got migrated.