# Migrations are now in progress

Tags: discussion, mso-mse-split, migration

I'm now in the process of migrating relevant content that is extremely specific to Stack Overflow back over the fence. To be very clear *this is a process that is going to take days, not hours*. Criteria for what I'm sending over varies from tag to tag, however the bulk of it is:

- Tag related discussions in the last 90 days that don't *appear* to be resolved (as far as having status-completed assigned to them)
- Stack Overflow *general* discussions, first grabbed by the stackoverflow tag, and then whittled down by date (last 30 days), no status tags, and score (more on that later)
- Support related discussions specific to SO in the last 30 days filtered by having other control tags, and by score.

Why by score, you ask? I'll tell you why, because it's the best indication that I'm *not* sending over a relic of someone being question blocked and not reading before posting about it. *This is not, by any means, a comprehensive process;* it's a process of running a series of queries, bringing up the posts, refining the query based on what I see in the results, then feeding post ID's to the bulk migration tool, then feeding some arrays into my browser console to make sure tags get created and carry over.

Said tool, which I fondly call the SuperMultiColliding RainbowQuestionChucker™ puts the questions I tag into a queue, where they trickle in.

*After* I've spent a couple of days at this, you're welcome to go flag things that weren't sent over *that are*:

- Still relevant, preferably undecided and actionable - people should have something to do other than say "Oh, that's nice" once it's migrated
- Not in the FAQ or FAQ-proposed family (not yet certain where we're going with that)
- Extremely specific to Stack Overflow itself

There *will* be bad migrations. I initially wanted to limit the number of things sent over to roughly 200 - 250, it's looking like I'm going to exceed that - I give everything a cursory glance but a few cow piles might land. Just reject those migrations (e.g. a programming question that somehow escaped deletion).

This isn't going to be gentle, but it's got to get done, so I'm letting everyone know I'm at it. It's also not the first time I've done this, so *hopefully* there won't be much mayhem - but it's better to let folks know it's coming :)

Comment: And for those of us with 10k wanting to review the migrations, go look at the [incoming migrations list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/here).

Comment: For the benefit of those who don't know, how, pray tell, does one *reject* a migration?

Comment: Yeah, please do - I'm shooting an elephant gun with carnival sights.

Comment: @Undo Why, good question. You close it as anything other than a duplicate.

Comment: Note: some careers stuff might be coming over as some are lumped in such a way that it's difficult to filter them all - _some_ are more about SO than anything else, I suggest we wait till I finish then look at that tag in general, since we'll _probably_ keep it / them.

Comment: Not the MSE rep means all that much, but any idea on how many users will loose major privileges as a result (users dropping below 2K, 3K, and 10K)?  I'm wondering how much whine there will be afterward.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Minimal (did I mention I'm steering a bit by score and age?) - there is going to be some, it's unavoidable, but I don't think it's going to hit anyone _too_ hard.

Comment: (110 more coming over in the queue, I'm trying to keep it at small batches, probably not going to do too many more with the bulk tool).

Comment: Should we be rejecting migrations if they're not really appropriate, or only if they're _terrible_? For example, [How to deactivate uniconis addon?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251079) doesn't really fit the criteria for migration: its time is past, and it wasn't specific to SO anyways, but it's not exactly _problematic_ either (although I'll edit it if it stays).

Comment: "undecided and actionable" - so is that all of the uncompleted clean-up / burninate / synonym / blacklist / retag requests that has a score of around +0? And none of those with a convincingly how / low score (or is "decided and actionable" also okay)?