# How should we handle Google Code answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, clean-up

Today I was mentally grumbling at a link-only Google Code answer that wasn't very clear, when it occurred to me that very soon, almost all Google Code related answers are going to break, because [Google Code is shutting down](http://google-opensource.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html).

We have until the end of the year (roughly) before Google Code goes completely poof. Fixing things while google code is still up will probably make it easier to follow things up, like where the new repos might be living (if anywhere).

There are a few different categories of questions that may "break", though. I propose the following:

1. **Link-only answers:** like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483063/1542891) should probably be deleted regardless of the fact that google code is dying.
2. **Links to GC repos in legit questions:** These are questions that *could* survive without links to a repo, and all relevant code is in the question or answer, but are enhanced by having the link. To handle these, it's probably best to attempt to link to the new github/whatever repo if it can be found. This would be loads of work, but would make sure the answers were still good quality.
3. **Questions about using Google Code:** Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084188/how-to-download-source-code-from-code-google-com) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105563/hide-source-file-on-code-google-com). I assume there is probably a policy for handling completely defunct questions, but I'm not sure what it is.

Only problem? An SO search for code.google.com comes up with <strike>~50,000 results</strike> [>120,000](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Acode.google.com) questions. The results of leaving it unfixed will be pretty drastic, but it's a mind boggling amount of work to fix and I can't imagine how to automate it.

=====

**Quick update**: [Stephane's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296919/1542891) below looks like a good way to handle most of the legit questions. Does anyone know if there's a policy for handling obsolete questions, like in category 3 above?

Comment: Yeah  this is an issue. We were supposed to be putting all the relevant code within the question itself, I think. Many of the questions may be old enough to have become obsolete though?    But I'm guessing it will sort itself out somehow

Comment: It will... but if we have the power to prevent the mass obsolescence of tens of thousands of questions before it happens... we should?

Comment: @yochannah - touche. Is there a way to grab the ones from within a year(ideally the quality ones), and then separate it out as a sort of "community volunteering edit-effort"  -  I wonder if there's a way to count-down how many posts still need fix-ups, as we continually whittle away at the problem . Because yes, this cannot be automated(someone needs to eyeball the code to bring in only the relevant code )

Comment: Actually, it would be in Google's interest to help Stackoverflow sort this out. They're the ones pulling the rug from under us so maybe they should help find a way to auto-migrate

Comment: @Coffee but migrated to where or what? the service is discontinued, project owners need to migrate their code. Maintainers that doesn't show up will have no new location except the tarballs....

Comment: I'm really not sure if or how this needs to be tackled. There are [25714](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3acode.google.com%20is%3aanswer%20score%3a..0%20isaccepted%3ano) low quality answers and about [3047](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Acode.google.com+is%3Aquestion++answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) questions with no answer. That leaves 100K of posts that currently have some value.

Comment: How about we start with [answers containing that link, not closed, not a duplicate, with 200+ views](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Acode.google.com+is%3Aanswer+closed%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+views%3A200). Sadly cant filter on "not containing a code block".

Comment: Doing what exactly @Sumurai8 ? close? delete? edit? leave a comment?

Comment: @rene: Someone can probably write a simple script that analyzes these answers to see which are likely to need user input (can a sede query be used?). My reasoning is that 120.000 q&a is too much to do something with. If we have to choose a subset of q&a, we should prefer checking open q&a that have a decent amount of views (and thus relevance).

Comment: @Sumurai8 I agree (I think) on the script part and if the results stay within 50000 rows SEDE could be used. But I'm more worried about what the *likely to need user input* will be? Just pick a handful of posts from your search and see if you come up with a small set of guidelines so we could start something similar like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295218/578411). Even if we want to automate/mechanical turk the action we need to know where to look for...and I can't form a clear picture of that action in my mind yet.

Comment: Seems we need a new review queue, possibly with sub-queues: One where we can put all questions/answers matching a query in for collaborative (optionally one-shot) reviewing.

Comment: How about a single comment to every OP that has a post with the link in it with the request to either add the code form the link to the post, update the link to the new location or remove the link all together.

Comment: @rene Combine both suggestions, send a comment automatically to every post that has a link to code.google.com asking the user to change their post (include a link to this question for reference). Then check after a certain period of time has passed and any that haven't been edited since the comment was left will be sent to a review queue. That way the majority of the work will be (hopefully) done by the users that left the post, and the rest will (I think) mostly be deletion of link-only or obsolete posts.

Comment: Keep in mind that none of this exist yet. I checked in the Tavern if some of the tools used by the CharCoal team could be used which seems to be the case but not without tweaks. That would give use an off-site review queue. Leaves open the comments to be send to users which could start with a [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/325748#resultSets) but I don't feel comfortable doing a mass-mailing...

Comment: @yochannah The problem looks like solved (see my update).

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert Thanks for the update! I had been wondering, actually! :)

Comment: Do you mind accepting it if that answers all your questions? :)

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert thanks for the reminder! :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Update 6 months later: problem solved by itself.**

Google made the sensible choice to redirect each links to their respective archived links. For instance: [code.google.com/p/phpquery/](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) now redirects to [code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/).

So finally there is nothing to do on SO's side!

---

From [Chris DiBona](http://www.dibona.com) (works at Google):

> We are planing on taking the majority of these legitimate, open
>   source, 'abandonded' projects and putting them up in cold storage in a
>   git repo on googlesource.com
>
> Source: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9192554

Once Google Code is down or the new repo is created, the Stack Exchange team could run a script that finds all `code.google.com/repo/file` links and change them to something which will most probably look like `googlesource.com/oldgooglecode/repo/file`.

Comment: I think this should mention the old link, strike it and post a new link, instead of just replacing the links. So as to keep a record of what really happened.

Comment: @noob Why? If this goes forward a new revision of the post is created...

Comment: Yeah, but that just striked in my head that what if the new link doesn't follow a proper standard. For example what if code.google.com/repo/file is not exactly replaceable with a proper URL. Or what if the Google code repo is dropped completely. They are going to migrate only few of them. So people should know the actual link to at least use Google cached view etc. to get the old code. It's hard to automate this IMO, so keeping an abandoned link might help. And not everyone know how to look for revisions or if the post actually had revisions.

Comment: We can't say until we know how the new Git repo on googlesource.com is structured, but as you mentioned there will be some particular cases to take care of.

Comment: @noob We have edit revision history for that don't we?

Comment: @Anthon How many time do you actually look at the revision history when using an answer? How do you supposed to know if the post has been edited out due to the Google Code shutdown and have been redirected to a new url which may or may not work. If there's a striked out content or even a yellow banner, users will know that they need to look at the revision history or at least they would know that the edit was automated without opening the revision history. I have never looked at the history of edits before using an answer, so there's one case at least.

Comment: I actually look relatively often at the revision history of posts and I would find a strikeout of the original URL in the post too much distraction if not absolutely necessary (which is hopefully the case). A smaller inline marker linking to an explanation might be more appropriate e..g a clickable `[orig]` text, I would find that more acceptable than a full strikeout

Comment: @noob We have to wait and see what they ultimately do. We have code laying around that sends gracious HTTP HEAD requests to verify the target gives a 200 status, it's something we built a long time ago to try and get link rot in front of reviewers. While we never opened the queue, we could make use of it in something that handles the lion's share of these edits automatically when the time comes.

Comment: @TimPost That's another good idea. Anthon If there's a simple indication that the current URL is changed via script, that's enough. Obviously if it's changed manually using a separate revision queue then it's not needed.

Answer (score 22):

Addressing these separately:

***Link-only answers***

If they're useful, try to pull some context out of whatever is being linked and put it into the answer. If the answer is basically *just use this*, then take a hard look at the question itself.

If they're just a half-assed attempt at answering something, they should probably be deleted.

***Links to repos in high quality posts***

*Hopefully* Google does something to avoid breaking these altogether, we have to see what that might be. Stéphane Bruckert's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296919/50049) gives me hope. If these links can be practically re-written and re-baked, we might be able to do that, just like we did when [we split MSE away from MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250024/the-status-of-the-split).

If you're looking for something to do, and notice an opportunity to help 'future proof' something good by pulling context out of the linked resource and into the question (where it's possible to do so), then by all means do it, but that's not exclusive to existentially-challenged code hosting services :)

***All those questions about Google code***

Nothing to do here. It existed, developers used it, and then it didn't exist any longer. It's just part of the site, and part of the history of doing our jobs. Continuing to have these questions won't hurt anything, we've got plenty of room. There's no real set policy, just an understanding that things sometimes lose relevance quickly.

Who knows, there might come a day when *nobody* uses CVS anymore, but we've got an amazing collection of [1300+ heads slamming on desks](https://stackoverflow.com/?show=all&sort=newest&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=cvs) for our children's children to read about.

Comment: A deletionist would hope Google does its very best to break the links as soon as possible just so they can drive the point home, usefulness be damned.

Comment: I dug a bit. The good news is we have some time to get ahead of this. The bad news is handling links to a specific revision / etc is going to be .. hard. I'm going to raise this to core dev internally (while we still have time to get ahead of it).

Comment: I still use CVS at work. *sob*

Answer (score 11):

This is a good idea and it should be done in multiple steps, starting with a clean-up of material that can be updated fully automatically, followed by human effort supported by a website that offers information and keeps track of what has already been handled.

Some people, already moved their 
code from google somewhere else, as can be seen when following links
in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/1307905) from Jon Skeet. Therefore for each of the 100K answers and 25K questions a check should be made whether the URL redirects somewhere else. 
If so the URL should be updated automatically.

For the other posts information about how much code lines (indented by 4) are available, how many views the question got, upvotes on questions and answers, and last visit to SO of the poster of the question /answer should influence priority and type of action taken.

If people have been active recently, a comment could be added to their post asking to update their posts and especially the links in a way the see fit within the next X days because of the changes at google.code.

As I don't think there has to be complete consensus on what order should be followed for manually updating answers. An online site where the above information is presented should allow ordering according to the potential reviewers needs.

This can all be done outside of SO, although not as efficient, and I am not sure about the "legality" of automatic updates of URLs.

But in the case of a user initiative, as rechecking links for changes is relatively expensive the site should be setup so that links to the material on SO are indirect so that clicking on a description redirects to the SO site, but also stores information that it is likely that the post will change.